# Is there a built-in HTML validator in any major browser?

Tags: html, html-parsing

In Firefox, there's a Extension called “Html Validator”. It adds a little indicator icon at the bottom right corner of your window. When a page you visit isn't valid, it lights up. You can click on it to see the errors. The really important feature of this extension is that it does not make a connection to w3c's validator. The same validating SGML parser used by w3c is bundled. This means it can validate local HTML files. (This is most the important use for me, as I do web development with manually coded html files. Each time I preview my HTML in a browser, I can also know whether it has validation errors.)

Is there anything similar in Google Chrome, Opera, Safari, or even IE? When I looked in the past years, all other validator I've seen simply send the current url to w3c's validator site.

Comment: I also need an answer to this question. My work requires that I not volunteer the source code to any system but my own.

Comment: Well, HTML (or any SGML dialect, or even XML) needs to validate against a DOCTYPE, therefore you **need** a program to do it for you, afaik there are no such tool (at least cross-browser) to do that. The best way would be to go with some W3C Api to check against.

Comment: You can grab the source to either [validator.nu](http://about.validator.nu/) or the [w3 html validator](http://validator.w3.org/about.html) and install locally. Once that's done, it'd be pretty easy to pipe the page to your local install of the validator.

Comment: It looks like "HTML Validator" hasn't been updated to work with Firefox 42. I'm looking for another option too. I haven't found anything else as easy or full featured and hope it gets updated soon. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/html-validator/

Answer (score 12):

I am the author of the Firefox extension. I have recently rewritten it for Chrome and the new Webextension API of Firefox.

See more info on the extension homepage:

> http://users.skynet.be/mgueury/mozilla/index.html

The direct link from the Google Chrome store is this:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html-validator/mpbelhhnfhfjnaehkcnnaknldmnocglk

Enjoy,

Answer (score 5):

There is a new HTML validator available for Chrome. It uses a JavaScript port of LibTidy and thus validates locally without the need of remote services.

See https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/anjdemaoejlpgmnmkijdemoiebcddhkc

Comment: "new" ... time has passed. There is no update since 8 years.

Answer (score 2):

[HTML Validator by Robert Nyman](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/cgndfbhngibokieehnjhbjkkhbfmhojo) for Google Chrome has an indicator icon, displays inline results, and validates local files.

Comment: nice tool. I tried it, but doesn't seems to work. Half of the time it tells me times out?

Comment: it might be using the w3C validator behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML Tidy Browser Extension works quite well, although it doesn't have as many features as the Firefox counterpart. As an added bonus, it works on localhost pages. You can get it here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html-tidy-browser-extensi/gljdonhfjnfdklljmfaabfpjlonflfnm

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that type of thing is usually built in, because they aren't needed by the average user and can slow down your browsing. Generally speaking, add-ons are the way to go, in my humble opinion.

The top two browser additions for anyone who is developing any website are: Firebug (as mentioned by a previous response) and the Web Developer toolbar, available for many browsers. Here is a link to the developer's page for the toolbar: [Website for Web Developer Toolbar](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/)

Firebug is great for stepping through JavaScript, detecting errors, checking out your HTML & CSS, as well as a plethora of other useful features.

The Web Developer Toolbar on the other hand, allows you to Validate HTML, CSS, etc, either on a local host, or on the web, turn off Javascript, turn off CSS, plus much more!

I hope this helps!

Comment: "I don't think that type of thing is usually built in, because they aren't needed by the average user and can slow down your browsing." Then why is an entire JavaScript debugger and DOM inspector built into Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Internet Explorer, and Edge? (Seriously, just press F12.)

Answer (score -1):

I am using this plugin in Chrome:
https://github.com/renyard/validity

Simple enough to use.
But I think there will be better to have a native tool in Chrome / Firefox.